# Is there a way to do spread operations with TypeScript generics?

Tags: generics, typescript

I have a function that takes in an object and merges it with another object. I would like to be able to have a generic T which represents the object that is being taken in that that Typescript knows the output object contains the same keys but also has the new keys.

```
export interface ObjFactory<T> {
  someNewProp: string
  otherNewProp: string
  ...T
}

export interface InputObject {
  inputProp: string
}
```

Then the output object would be represent as

```
{
  someNewProp: string
  otherNewProp: string
  inputProp: string
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something similar to this?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Type Intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to achieve this if you're comfortable exporting `type`s instead of interfaces.

```
export type ObjFactory<T> = T & {
  someNewProp: string
  otherNewProp: string
}

export interface InputObject {
  inputProp: string
}
```

The only downside to `type` AFAIK is classes and interfaces can't extend them.